# Trouble understanding the function of : in array indexing? Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have this line in the code:

`next_J[v] = np.min(Q[v, :] + J)`

Where essentially Q is an matrix of size n x n and J is a vector of size n. What does Q[v, :] mean?

I tried to code this out but still do not understand what exactly it does.

Comment: "Note that `::` is the same as `:` and means select all indices along this axis." - [numpy slicing and striding](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding)

Comment: @matszwecja when I try run this code it gives me the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: This means Q is not a numpy array

Comment: Is Q a list of lists or a numpy array? You should provide more context

Comment: @matszwecja, I want to do the same thing on a list of lists. The original code was on a numpy array. I just want to understand what it actually does so I can translate that.

Comment: `Q[v, :]` means every element with first index equal to `v` and 2nd index can be anything, so effectively, `v`-th row.

Comment: It's a simple element-wise sum of 2 vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Q[v,:]` is translated by the interpreter as `Q.__getitem__((v, slice(None))`

Note the `(,)` tuple syntax.

For a 2d array, this means select the `v` row.  The slice selects all columns, and isn't actually needed in this context.

For a list this produces an error.  `alist[v]` would work.

`Q[v]+J` may not work fot lists, depending on what `J` is. `+` is different for lists. The class of an object is important in understanding code.

The use of `:` in python indexing is basic.  So is its use jn numpy indexing.

There's a lot more about using `slicing` with `numpy` arrays at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding